# Message passing from content script not working chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write ann application where a message is passed from a content script to the background page, and a response it send back. The response always comes back undefined. The string of numbers is my extension ID by the way.

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("lnomjdakniinmllkpmoghlclloppbnph",{greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.farewell);
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
            "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
            "from the extension");
if (request.greeting == "hello")
  sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
});
```

Comment: It should work this way. Maybe just a typo in the extension ID? Did you ever try to omit it? It's not mandatory so you should give it a try. Is this exactly your code or did you reduce the example? I'm asking because there is a special situation when you call sendResponse asynchronously ...

Comment: I tried that earlier, but it throws the error 'Invalid Arguments to Connect'.

Comment: Could you also post your `manifest.json` file? Just want to confirm `content.js` is correctly declared.

Comment: I was updating an extension for another client, and the problem seemed to be rooted in the faulty extension I was given. I am able to pass messages in a standard environment though,